# Mail Merge with Multiple Fields Using Commas and 'And'

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, mailmerge

I have a mail merge with a section that has to display the results of multiple fields using commas and 'and' depending on the resulting values.

For example: *If value A, B, and D values start with "New" then display them (New Brakes, New Tires and New Wipers)*. However, I don't want to show C (whose value is 'Fluids' and doesn't include the word 'New') and I need to format the results adding commas and 'and'.

Columns in order are: brakes, tires, fluids, wipers, oil. Attributes (brakes) are New Brakes, Old Brakes, Ok Brakes; (tires) New Tires, Old Tires, Ok Tires...

Here is where I'm at:

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD brakes }="New*" "New Brakes" ""}{ IF { MERGEFIELD fluids }="" " and { MERGEFIELD tires }" ",{ IF { MERGEFIELD tires }="New*" "New Tires" ""}{ IF { MERGEFIELD oil}=" " and { MERGEFIELD wipers}" ",...
```

I'm getting results such as:

```
, ,New Fluids
```

and other incorrectly formatted answers. I appreciate any ideas on tweaking this logic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem statement isn't clear. I don't see anything in your fields that checks about "New" - "New" appears irrelevant to the field code you're trying to build? The result you're looking for also isn't clear; it would help if you'd give examples of the expected result combinations, including the data each mergefield includes for these results.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister I realized it was vague after reading it again but hopefully the edits provide further details and I appreciate your suggestions and comments.

Comment: What's your data source? My gut feeling is that it would be best to handle this in the data source. If this were a Database, for example, I'd create a look-up table for the text and store corresponding ID numbers in the query/table you're using as the data source. If it's Excel, I might create additional columns that contain a value you can test directly in the IF field. If fields simply do not have the capability of "wildcard matching" or other string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I managed to solve it using Alteryx ;)